# div elements acting abnormally after adding transformation in CSS

Tags: html, css, transform, transition, visual-web-developer

This is my document.

**TL;DR - Hover over the two div elements repeatedly to notice their behaviour.**

```css
body {
  margin: 10rem;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 2rem;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: larger;
  background-color: aqua;
}

div#fun {
  top: 18rem;
  transform: perspective(200px) translateZ(50px) rotateZ(30deg) skew(-20deg, -5deg);
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 3s;
}

div#fun:hover {
  transform: unset;
}

div#move {
  transition: right 2s;
}

div#move:hover {
  right: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<h1>Trying to be creative</h1>
<div id="move">Move</div>
<br> <br>
<div id="fun">Fun?!</div>
```

When you hover over the div with id **move** it sometimes keeps rapidly changing its positions, although sometimes it doesn't. I don't know the reason behind this behaviour.
On hovering over the second div **fun** it behaves almost normally as it should, as mentioned in the transform property. But after repeatedly hovering over it, it increases its size so much that it looks like it's *popping out* of the screen.

Sorry if i'm being a little blunt, but i've tried to explain my issue to the best of my capabilities. I'm pretty new to CSS. Any kind suggestions and help is welcomed and highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As you're using a CSS `transition`, the `#move` `div` needs an initial value for the `right` property to transition from.

```css
div#move {
  right: 0;
  transition: right 2s;
}

div#move:hover {
  right: 10rem;
}
```